# Struggling with rosjava and android tutorials

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally got the code installed, and built some how,, I even got the PubSubTutorial to download to my Samsung S but code keeps crashing at new WebServer.

```
  public NodeServer(BindAddress bindAddress, AdvertiseAddress advertiseAddress) {
    InetSocketAddress address = bindAddress.toInetSocketAddress();
    server = new WebServer(address.getPort(), address.getAddress());
    this.advertiseAddress = advertiseAddress;
    this.advertiseAddress.setPortCallable(new Callable() {
      @Override
      public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return server.getPort();
      }
    });
    startLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  }
```

Any ideas?

Do I need to have a ROScore running on the phone, cant I just run a node on the phone and the Core/Master on my PC?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10646/struggling-with-rosjava-and-android-tutorials/) by [Micke](https://answers.ros.org/users/857/micke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-07-21**:
Could you provide some more information? A stack trace would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without posting more information this question cannot be answered, please follow the guidelines here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0